# Watch property on Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3, watch

I have a form that I am editing, and i use the created method to prefill that form information from api call and that all works fine.

However I want to watch the fields in the form, and if they get edited i want to set a variable "isFormEdited" to be true.

I have it set up like this.

```
   watch: {
  'form': {
    handler: function(v) {
      console.log('form changed')
    //here i would set the "isFormEdited" variable to be true. 
    },
    deep: true
  },
```

My problem is that the console log happens immediately on page load, because the form goes from empty, then the created function fills the values with the api call.

How can I get around this so that I can have a "isFormEdited" value only set true when the form was actually changed manually?

```
created() {


      const getForm = axios.get(`api/dashboard/form/${this.$route.params.id}/edit`);
      const getFormTypes = axios.get('api/dashboard/form/types');

      axios.all([getForm, getFormTypes])
          .then(
              axios.spread((...responses) => {
                  // console.log(responses[0].data);
                  this.form = responses[0].data;

                  if(!this.form.type_id) this.form.type_id = ""; //Set Blank if null

                  this.form.fields.map((field) => {
                     // console.log(field);
                     if(field.options){ field.options = JSON.parse(field.options); }
                     if(field.mime_types_allowed){  field.mime_types_allowed = JSON.parse(field.mime_types_allowed); }
                     return field;
                  });

                  //get form types
                  this.types = responses[1].data.data;
              })
          )
          .catch(errors => {
              alert("Error");
              console.log(errors);
      });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional variable `dataLoaded`, set it to false by default, and change it to true when you have populated your form. Then in your `watch` handler, you would only set `isFormEdited` to true when `dataLoaded` is true as well.

Example:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dataLoaded: false,
            isFormEdited: false,
        };
    },
    created() {
        const getForm = axios.get(`api/dashboard/form/${this.$route.params.id}/edit`);
        const getFormTypes = axios.get('api/dashboard/form/types');

        axios
            .all([getForm, getFormTypes])
            .then(
                axios.spread((...responses) => {
                    // console.log(responses[0].data);
                    this.form = responses[0].data;

                    if (!this.form.type_id) this.form.type_id = ''; //Set Blank if null

                    this.form.fields.map((field) => {
                        // console.log(field);
                        if (field.options) {
                            field.options = JSON.parse(field.options);
                        }
                        if (field.mime_types_allowed) {
                            field.mime_types_allowed = JSON.parse(field.mime_types_allowed);
                        }
                        return field;
                    });

                    //get form types
                    this.types = responses[1].data.data;

                    this.dataLoaded = true;
                })
            )
            .catch((errors) => {
                alert('Error');
                console.log(errors);
            });
    },
    watch: {
        form: {
            handler: function (v) {
                if (this.dataLoaded) {
                    console.log('Form changed!');
                    this.isFormEdited = true;
                }
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },
};
```

If this is not an option, you could use the instance's [`$watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#watch) method to start watching a data element at any point in your component.